# How to boot an MBP from an external HD?

Tags: mac, boot, external-hard-drive, macbook-pro, superduper

I created a clone partition of my main drive with SuperDuper on an external (USB) drive.  How can I boot from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press and hold the 'Option' key when you first start your Mac, which should then show you a list of bootable drives.  You should then be able to select your external drive and go.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Brad's answer, before you shut down you can connect the external disk, open the "Startup Disk" system preference item, and pick the startup image that you want.